# How to Persist an enum as integer or shortint in ServiceStack.OrmLite?

Tags: orm, servicestack

As a default, enum properties are stored as varchar(8000) in Sql Server. How can I store as shortint or int?

```
public enum MyEnum
{
   EnumA=1,
   EnumB=2,
   EnumC=3
}
```

Not fragile.

Comment: Is that really a good idea? The enum is an abstraction, the constant in behind may change. You would be making your code more fragile.

Comment: Enum members can be taken a constant number. I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution for it. You have to implement your own Enum as int wrapper.